# How to collect the "victory resource" in Catacomb Snatch?

Tags: catacomb-snatch

I've bombed my way to the pink... liquid in the middle of the catacomb, I've connected it through rails to my base... but nothing seems to happen. Shooting at it doesn't do anything either, although turrets do target it... Bombing does nothing...

What am I supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must press the railway bulding/removing key on the very first piece of rail, one tile above/below your flag. That creates a (rather dumb) bot for 100 coins that can collect 2% of the "victory resource" for you.

These robots aren't too smart, so don't throw anything too complicated at them. The rails just need to go from your base to the center and back.